# How to call function containing intent (in Activity A) from Activity B

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am Calling a function(present in fragment) from activity when back button is pressed

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    new Home().show(Home.home_list,app.this);                   
}
```

Home is fragment of app activity

In show function I am calling an intent

```
public void show(final ArrayList<tile_data> data, final Activity activity) {
    startActivity(new Intent(activity, Chat_topic_layout_for_user_group.class)
}
```

In doing so it gives me error :                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Home{5deabab} not attached to Activity

My conclusion is that app is using show as function so it doesn't know about home.

So my question is how to call an "intent" present in some function in some activity or fragment from other activity??

Comment: try `activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Chat_topic_layout_for_user_group.class)`

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks !!!! it worked . I kinda stuck in it from a long time

Comment: Take a look at this library: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `startActivity` is not being called in the right scope. Try specifying the scope and calling it like this: `activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Chat_topic_layout_for_user_group.class)`

Comment: Yes, I am missing the scope. I am keep adding the 1st parameter of intent. Hadn't think about changing scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void show(final ArrayList<tile_data> data, final Activity activity) {
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Chat_topic_layout_for_user_group.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the `Show()` function to the `Activity`? And for the titles create a getter function in the `Home fragment`, `getTitles()`. Now, when the event occurs trigger the `Show()` function directly in the activity passing `(*HomeFragment*.getTitle() , *Activity*.this)`. Are your titles `static`? Because you are directly calling `new Home()`. If that's the case there won't be any issue in calling `Show()` function in the activity. You can explain your requirements in detail if this isn't up to par.

Comment: Yeah its a good idea. But there are many other parameters involved in show function which are solely related to home. The Show function is using them so I cant move it to app.